# Free sends per subaccounts in Mandrill

Tags: mandrill

I have a free account in Mandrill
How many emails I can send if I make two subaccounts?
12000 (based on main account) or 24000 (per each subaccounts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing happens at the account level, not subaccount level. Your account as a whole will get 12,000 free sends each month.